# Sort 2 different lists to the same positions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to sort a list of people names, but the other list of contacts must be sorted as well to stay with the same index so that the contact corresponds to the name.
I've this class:

```
        List<string> name = new List<string>();
        List<string> cellphone = new List<string>();

        public void setName(string value)
        {
            name.Add(value);
        }
        public void setCellphone(string value)
        {
            cellphone.Add(value);
        }

        public List<string> getNames()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public List<string> getCellphones()
        {
            return cellphone;
        }
```

now i'd like to have them sorted;

e.g:

List 1:
  - Joseph
  - Anna

List 2:
  - +351912345678
  - +351931234567

the result must be:

List 1:
  - Anna
  - Joseph

List 2:
  - +351931234567
  - +351912345678

Comment: Why don't you just use a Dictionary?

Comment: Why not do a "Person" class? You won't have to handle 2 (or more if you get more data types eventually) lists everywhere and if you order them by name they'll always be coupled correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using single class to hold information on a person.

Now to the question: [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) + [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) + 2 *( [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) + [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)) can give you sorted list in the same order. Something like:

```
 var pairs = name.Zip(cellphone, (name, phone)=> new {name, phone})
     .OrderBy(item => item.name);

 name = pairs.Select(item => item.name).ToList();
 cellphone = pairs.Select(item => item.phone).ToList();
```

Comment: this only order the names, not the contacts.

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano, not sure I follow - question is reorder 2 lists so first one is sorted and indexes of second reordered to match first, second list is not expected to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Dictionary and not 2 Lists.  See here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Or create a lightweight struct or class to add if there is a chance of dupes in the key.

Comment: @Mike Cheel The framework already has a structure for that called a Lookup. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx